# Tensorflow tf.expand_dims

Tags: tensorflow

The [original Tensorflow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/0.6.0/tutorials/mnist/tf/index.html) includes the following code:

```
batch_size = tf.size(labels)
labels = tf.expand_dims(labels, 1)
indices = tf.expand_dims(tf.range(0, batch_size, 1), 1)
concated = tf.concat(1, [indices, labels])
onehot_labels = tf.sparse_to_dense(concated, tf.pack([batch_size, NUM_CLASSES]), 1.0, 0.0)
```

The second line adds a dimension to the `labels` tensor. However, `labels` was fed in via a feed dictionary so it should already have shape `[batch_size, NUM_CLASSES]`. If so then why is `expand_dims` used here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That tutorial is pretty old. You're referencing version 0.6 whereas they are at 0.11 as of (11-20-2016 time of this post). So there were many functions that were different at that time v0.6.

Anyways to answer your question:

The labels in mnist were just encoded as the digits 0-9. however, the loss function expected the labels to be encoded as a one hot vector.

The labels are not already `[batch_size, NUM_CLASSES]` in that example it was just `[batch_size]`.

This could have been done via similar numpy functions.  Also they have also since provided functions to get the labels from the mnist dataset in tensorflow as one hot vectors which do already have the shape you stated.